# Cannot open a gpg file on another machine (`gpg: decryption failed: No secret key`)

Tags: gnupg, passphrase, gpg-agent

I want to open a gpg file on a Linux system which has been encrypted on another machine (in that case the OS was also different as it was a macos machine).

```
gpg --output out --decrypt youfirst.gpg
gpg: encrypted with ECDH key, ID DF6654173D738ED1
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I tried to follow this answer:
[gpg decryption fails with no secret key error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28321712/gpg-decryption-fails-with-no-secret-key-error)

namely, I restarted the gpg-agent which was then runnging:

```
$ gpg-agent
gpg-agent[5846]: gpg-agent running and available
```

But I still get the error. What am I doing wrong