# Avoid re-entering password for each submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo with 3 submodules. The repo and submodules are all on the same server, which I have ssh access to. The remote URLs are:

```
ssh://mm@theserver.com/path/to/sub1.git
ssh://mm@theserver.com/path/to/sub2.git
ssh://mm@theserver.com/path/to/sub3.git
```

If I do an operation such as `git submodule update --remote` then it prompts for my password 3 times.

Is there any way to update the submodules but only require password once?  Same goes for committing changes etc.

Comment: if you have server access, you can add your machine key to authorized_keys file of the server

Comment: use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store; the example in that page is using `https`, but I feel `ssh://matt:password@theserver.com` would work as well.

Answer (score 16):

### Solution that requires much less headache

Another approach is to use built-in [git cache](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) (v. 1.7.10 or newer required) so git will remember your login and password after you provide it first time.

To enable git cache with default timeout (15 min) you type

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

To change default timeout type

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Comment: This did not work, after trying either of those commands it still prompts me to "Enter passphrase for key" on every attempt to update from a remote. Using git 2.8.3.  The page you link to suggests that the git cache is only useful for https connections, whereas I'm connecting via ssh (and the passphrase is for my local private key).  The link to SSH on your link does say "You can secure your SSH keys and configure an authentication agent so that you won't have to reenter your passphrase every time you use your SSH keys.", but it doesn't elaborate on how to do that.

Answer (score 10):

**Credit:** this answer began with rjv's answer although I required several more steps to get it working nicely. Other source material is linked below.

**Background:** I'm using Cygwin in Windows, with a version of `git` built from source. I'm not using the Cygwin git although this should work the same for that. I am using Cygwin's `ssh`.  But the following method should work for unix-like systems also.

---

### Introduction

Firstly: it's not possible to "remember" the password inbetween invocations of git. (The `git submodule` is a script which invokes `git` once for each submodule here).

However, it is possible to remember [RSA key passphrases](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/) by using [ssh-agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90853/how-can-i-run-ssh-add-automatically-without-password-prompt). So the list of steps here is:

1. Create a RSA key pair for the ssh link.
2. Set up a `.ssh/config` entry for the `git` host
3. Set up `ssh-agent` to remember the passphrase -- either just for the duration of the current command; or for the duration of the current shell.

---

### Create RSA key pair

*If you already have a key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa` or otherwise that you wish to use, skip this step*

- Create a key pair with `ssh-keygen`. **[Use a strong passphrase](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/)**. For this answer let's assume the files are `mm_rsa` and `mm_rsa.pub`.  The default filename is `id_rsa` etc., however in this answer I will use a different name so that we can see how to specify the name. This could be useful if you wish to use different keys for different hosts.
- On the server:

  - Copy `mm_rsa.pub` into `~/.ssh`
  - Append `mm_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (creating it if it didn't exist)
- On the client:

  - Copy `mm_rsa` to `~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 mm_rsa` so that nobody else can read your private key.

At this point you could test things by opening an SSH connection using your usual `ssh` command, plus the option `-i ~/.ssh/mm_rsa`.

---

### Set up a ~/.ssh/config entry

In the [~/.ssh/config](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/) file (creating it if it didn't exist), create an entry like this:

```
Host the_git_host
    HostName bla.bla.com
    User mm
    Port 2222
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mm_rsa
```

After doing these steps, you should be able to connect via ssh simply by issuing the command `ssh the_git_host` after which it will prompt for your passphrase.[Link to more detail](https://superuser.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-set-up-ssh-so-i-dont-have-to-type-my-password)

Further, you will now be able to change your git remote to use `the_git_host` and then it will fish those details out of the `.ssh/config` file!

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://mm@bla.bla.com:2222/path/to/repo (fetch)
origin  ssh://mm@bla.bla.com:2222/path/to/repo (push)

$ git remote set-url origin ssh://the_git_host/path/to/repo
```

At this point you will be able to do `git remote update` and it will use the `mm_rsa` certificate, and prompt for your passphrase.

---

### Set up ssh-agent

`ssh-agent` is a daemon. To start it you run `ssh-agent -s`, but that is a bit tricksy. It wants to set environment variables so that other programs can communicate with it. However, instead of just setting them, it outputs them on the commandline. So to actually run `ssh-agent` you must write:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

which both launches ssh-agent and sets the environment variables.

To kill it later and clear the environment, use `ssh-agent -k`.

Once the agent is running then you remember your passphrase via the command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/mm_rsa
```

which will prompt for the passphrase. If you get the error "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent", [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent).

Finally, this is a bit annoying to have to type every time, so you can insert [this gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347344/1505939) into your `.bashrc` which will delay authentication until you issue a `git` command:

```
ssh-auth() {
    # Start the SSH agent only if not running
    [[ -z $(ps | grep ssh-agent) ]] && echo $(ssh-agent) > /tmp/ssh-agent-data.sh

    # Load the environment variables for ssh-agent
    source /tmp/ssh-agent-data.sh > /dev/null

    # Authenticate
    [[ -z $(ssh-add -l | grep "mm_rsa") ]] && ssh-add ~/.ssh/mm_rsa
}
```

This will persist the authentication for the rest of the current shell (or until you `ssh-agent -k`).

So, at long last, we can go:

```
$ ssh-auth
$ git submodule update --remote
```

Comment: Works on wsl2 ubuntu20.04 ask well.

Answer (score 2):

One solution might be adding your machine `ssh public key` to `authourized_keys` file of the server. After that, you will not be asked for password.

This is possible only if you have server access.

This is how you do it

- Copy your public key, usually present at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- Append the key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in your server.

After that, you can connect to the server without a password

Comment: Using this technique I get asked for private key passphrase 3 times, heh

Answer (score 1):

What all answers here fail to mention is that a prompt for username and password is most likely caused by updating a submodule that needs authentication, for example a **private** repository. I found this neat little detail here:

https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/

Quote

> The problem arises when sub-modules refer private Git repositories which cannot be cloned without authentication and as a result you get stalled build. This is because sub-module repository does not contain SSH public key used to authenticate main repo, so Git is asking for credentials:

This means you need to use SSH for cloning submodules. GitHub provides a nice [setup guide](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) with all the steps necessary (basically the short version of @M.M`s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30182235/3936440)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative path while adding the submodules. Run the command like below and use relative path:

`git submodule add ../test-git-sync.git`

`.gitmodules` file after adding the submodule will look like below

```
[submodule "test-git-sync"]
    path = test-git-sync
    url = ../test-git-sync.git # uses relative path
```