# Git hangs on initial push

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I've just started a new private project and wanted to push it to Bitbucket.
However, git just hangs after entering my ssh passphrase:

```
psirus|example» git push -u origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/psirus/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Unfortunately, nothing more useful can be found by using `-v`:

```
psirus|example» git push -v -u origin master 
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:psirus/example.git
Enter passphrase for key '/home/psirus/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

What else can I do to debug this problem? I can successfully push to my other Bitbucket repos, using this ssh key, this computer, this connection.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: I left it last night for hours. And there is basically just three text files of a couple of lines each in there.

Comment: @Psirus What OS do you use?

Comment: Arch Linux 64bit. Meanwhile, it worked. I've done nothing different. *shrug*

Comment: Try [$ eval `ssh-agent -s`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/3686755) `$ ssh-add /home/psirus/.ssh/id_rsa` `$ git push origin master`