# "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent" ,ssh-add error even after ssh-agent started

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I need to add multiple ssh keys , so i need to execute `ssh-add`

But I get error of `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`

I read multiply posts like [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent) and https://superuser.com/questions/901568/ssh-agent-could-not-open-connection

I had started the ssh-agent by

```
eval ($ssh-agent -s)
```

and the output is like :
    Agent pid 13524

but still get this error:

```
 $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I also set

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

And I echo some variable and get this:

```
echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
12340 
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK 
/tmp/ssh-ZbRZr10908/agent.10908
```

PS: I am using Windows 7 and the under company's network.

Answer (score 9):

I tried a lot of solutions online but nothing worked. I made more research and found that the following commands worked.

> 1. sudo ssh-agent bash
> 2. ssh-add /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 7):

You put the start of agent wrong. It should be:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

But if that will not help, anyway you can troubleshoot the issue by trying to write `env` variables:

```
echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

and making sure the socket (path from the second `echo`) exists and have reasonable ACL's. Also checking if the agent itself runs by the `PID`.

### Edit:

I see you are using windows, so there can be problem with the paths. Fortunately `ssh-agent` supports argument `-a` with the path to UNIX-domain socket or address to bind. You should try:

```
 ssh-agent -a ./agent_socket
```

or

```
 ssh-agent -a 127.0.0.1:9999
```

which should work even on windows.

Comment: No use.   eval $(ssh-agent -s)  -->"Agent pid 12340"
echo $SSH_AGENT_PID  -->12340
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK -->/tmp/ssh-ZbRZr10908/agent.10908

Comment: I see you are using windows. Is it under cygwin or how? If not, it is probable, that the path starting with `/tmp/` will not work for you.

Comment: hmm, I just use gitbash to execute these.

Comment: I believe there is problem with the path on windows. You should try to start `ssh-agent` with argument `-a ./agent_socket`. It should create the socket in current directory and then ssh-add should be able to connect to this socket ... hopefully. Otherwise you can try to bind some localhost address, which should work for sure: `ssh-agent -a 127.0.0.1:9999`