# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent (REVIEW)

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty

First of all, I am aware that this question has been posted several times in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083079/ssh-agent-error-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33227125/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent-ssh-add-error-even-a), as well as [in some other places](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48863/ssh-add-complains-could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent).

However, I decided to open a new thread (and taking the risk of being downvoted) because I don't think there is an actual issue with my machine, but with PUTTY.

**Environment description**

In a nutshell, I have a windows machine running a virtual machine (VMWare).

1. Host machine: Windows 7 (64 bit)
2. Guest machine: CentOS 6 with graphic windows environment.
3. Network connection perfectly setup, so no problems with firewall. Both machines are pingeable from each other, and I can surf the internet from both
4. Selinux disabled on guest machine
5. Putty is properly configured (or so I think). The reasons to back up the statement is that I can SSH the guest machine from the host machine with the encrypted SSH keys that I created for that matter. However, I think there is still some configuration missing. Keep reading.
6. I have configured GITOLITE on the guest machine, and it is up and running.
7. Although not relevant for this issue, I have a Samba share configured on the guest machine, were I have all my repos. The share is accessible from the host machine, and I can edit the files with no problem whatsoever.
8. VM Player 7
9. Guest machine recently restarted and no additional commands have been issued.
10. PUTTY installed in the host machine

**Case scenario #1 (it works)**

This case scenario describes the behaviour I expect to achieve. Basically, this procedure is being done *within* the VM itself. That means, *by operating the machine through the VM Player*.

1. Open a terminal as root
2. `service sshd status` yields *`openssh-daemon (pid 1557) is running...`*
3. `ssh-add -l` yields *`2048 1b:31 [...] b8:de Git Admin (RSA)`*, *`2048 d2:58 [...] f6:2b pando (RSA)`* and *`(2048) be:9b [...] dc:e9 web (RSA)`*. These are the three users I have configured in my virtual machine. The SSH keys have been automatically loaded and added to the list of identities of the SSH service.
4. Log out as root from the CLI. I am now an standard user (the `pando` user).
5. Edit one file in one of the repos
6. `git commit -a -m "My message"` is successful because the `Git Admin` key is in the identity list of the SSH agent
7. `git push origin master` is also successful, for the same reasons

**Case scenario #2 (it does not work)**

This case scenario describes the same procedure, but from the Putty terminal. I added to the Pageant the same SSH keys as described in Case Scenario #1, point 3. It looks like everything is Ok with Putty, because I can successfully SSH my virtual machine

1. Open the Putty Terminal. I am logged in as user `pando` (which is one of the identities mentioned in Case Scenario 1).
2. `su`
3. `service sshd status` yields *`openssh-daemon (pid 1557) is running...`* (notice that it is the same result as we got in point #2 of the first case scenario)
4. `ssh-add -l` yields *`Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`*
5. Because the previous step failed, I have all the issues described in the hyperlinked threads at the beginning of this post.

Now, I am familiar with that procedure of `eval $(ssh-agent)` and then to manually add the SSH keys on my SSH folder. In fact, I do that every time I SSH the virtual machine. But I actually prefer not to do it.

I am also familiar with adding some script to the `.bashsrc` file, but the last time I did it, I got a colateral effect with Puppet.

So the basic question is: What's the difference betwen both case scenarios, even though I am using the same SSH keys? Is it that Pageant is not forwarding the keys? If so, why am I able to SSH my machine? Why should I change the `.bashrc` file of my `pando` user in the second case scenario, when I can achieve exactly the same thing without it in the first case scenario? I guess I am missing a fundamental piece of information here

Hope that makes sense.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*openssh-daemon* and *authentication-daemon* are not the same thing. You are interested in the authentication one aka `ssh-agent`, which is your personal key-store. The *openssh-deamon* aka `sshd` is server that is running system-wide and which is accepting connections to your computer.

Desktop environments usually start authentication agents (`ssh-agent`, `seahorse`, `gnome-keyring`) by default so the `ssh-add` works for you. But the connection is stored in environment variables, which are dropped in transition from your user to superuser (`su`).

You can allow connection persistence using `-m` switch to `su`. This will preserve environment variables and so your connection to authentication agent.

---

> What's the difference between both case scenarios, even though I am using the same SSH keys?

There should be no difference, except the `su` part dropping environment variables and not executing `.bashrc` and similar scripts when changing user (you can force `su` to behave the same way as a login shell using `su -l`, but it is not the problem). The problem is that the connection to authentication agent is preserved as environment variable and UNIX domain socket, which gets lost during `su`. You can use `su -m` it should work for you.

> Is it that Pageant is not forwarding the keys?

Forwarding needs to be allowed in PuTTY:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jakuje. Please forgive my ignorance, but I still don't understand. Isn't that PUTTY another way to manipulate the machine? Isn't that true that once you are logged in, all the functionalities (e.g. commands, services, configurations, etc) are available in the same fashion as by manipulating the machine itself locally? If so, why in the first case the keys are loaded, but not in the second case? Perhaps you already answered this question, but I don't still see it. Best regards

Comment: That makes sense. I checked my Putty, and the highlighted option was disabled. I made two tests, one with my current config (forwarding disabled), and another with the new one (forwarding enabled). It worked. Thanks very much for your help. Best regards

Comment: Do you have to make this configuration for a session specifically targeting the server hosting the git repository? It seems to have no effect otherwise.

Comment: @DissidentRage which part do you mean?

Comment: "Allow agent forwarding" is not as specific as you'd think. Do you have to set this option for a specific connection?

Comment: @DissidentRage I don't know. I don't use putty. Give it a try. But for me it looks like for all connections from given session. But I believe you can create session with this option disabled or enabled.

Comment: In my case it doesn't work at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110079/git-bash-pageant-not-using-keys/35111050#35111050