# Can't connect to GitLab via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

Firstly, i created the ssh key pair with the command:

```
ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

Then, i added content of the id_rsa.pub file to my GitLab profile. 
But when i tried to test whether my SSH key was added correctly:

```
ssh -vvvT user@some.gitlab.com
```

i've got the following log after correct password was typed:

```
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to some.gitlab.com ([xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:xx).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last failed login: Sun Jan 26 21:33:13 UTC 2020 from some-freeipa.com on ssh:notty
```

And nothing else. Printing of log has stopped, and console is frozen now.
Also i've tried to clone some projects from my GitLab with command:

```
git clone ssh://user@some-gitlab-url/some-project.git
```

But i've got the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Could anyone, please, help me with the issue?

Comment: Does it work if you change your remote to use `git@` instead of `user@`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I've tried both: 1. 'git clone ssh://user@...' with 'ssh -vvvT user@some.gitlab.com' to test; 2. 'git clone ssh://git@...' with 'ssh -vvvT git@some.gitlab.com' to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shell request accepted on channel 0
```

That means possibly the ssh part is working.

What would not be working would be the URL used to cloned the repo:

- the users needs to be git (always in a typical GitLab installation)
- the URL needs to include the user/group and the repo

So not ssh://user@some-gitlab-url/some-project.git but

```
ssh://git@some-gitlab-url/some-group/some-project.git
```

As found [by the OP in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48434180#48434180), **the issue was the SSH library used**.

> The problem was with OpenSSH client.
>   During the discussion I was using OpenSSH client for Windows.
>   After it was changed to Git Bash it has started to work!

I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35111050/6309) that Windows 10 (1809+) adds an [OpenSSH Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) (and server).
But [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.24.0.windows.1) comes with [OpenSSH 8.1](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.1).

Since The Windows SSH is a fork ([`PowerShell/openssh-portable`](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable)) of the openSSH one, using the one from Git is safer.

More generally, using Git with a path *starting* with:

```
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

That will ensure you are using Git with its runtime dependencies first (and then Windows).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. The same result

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: Regarding the 'ssh://git@some-gitlab-url/some-group/some-project.git' format. Yes, i'm using this format, the 'ssh://user@some-gitlab-url/some-project.git' without group was used just to simplify.

Comment: Regarging the 'the users needs to be git (always in a typical GitLab installation)'. See my comment below the question: ' I've tried both: 1. 'git clone ssh://user@...' with 'ssh -vvvT user@some.gitlab.com' to test; 2. 'git clone ssh://git@...' with 'ssh -vvvT git@some.gitlab.com' to test'

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili Is it a private repo? Does your user (where you did register the public SSH key) has the right to access it through the Web GUI?

Comment: yes, it's corporative repo and i have access through Web GUI

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili The point (regarding `git@`) is that it does not make sense to use your login `user@` in an SSH URL: SSH does the authentication for you, under the service account `git` (which  runs the GitLab instance)

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili "And nothing else. Printing of log has stopped, and console is frozen now": that part is not OK: a GitLab instance should answer (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly): "Welcome to GitLab, @username!"

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili Can you try with `ssh -vvvT git@some.gitlab.com`? Again, "user" is never involved in a server for SSH connection.

Comment: Correct, this welcoming message is exactly what i'm expecting for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206685/discussion-between-vonc-and-ilya-berdzenishvili).

Comment: @IlyaBerdzenishvili I have updated the answer with your conclusion, and some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my answer, since I just spent about 4 hours resolving the issue for `Permission denied (publickey).`

I had to update the `.ssh/config` file with the following:

```
# Gitlab | example
Host <gitlabUserName>.gitlab.com
  Host gitlab.com
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<ssh_key_type>
```

You'll need to add your own gitlab user name for the Host on the second line

you'll need to add the ssh_key_type (rsa, id_ed25519, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or very similar) issue on Ubuntu 22.04, with the error message

```
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (172.65.251.78)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:eUXGGm1YGsMAS7vkcx6JOJdOGHPem5gQp4taiCfCLB8.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The [solution](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/error-host-key-verification-failed/77315) was to update `~/.ssh/config` with

```
Host *gitlab*
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Where the last line made the difference. Also [note](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html) that if using RSA keys they must be at least 2048 and maximum 8192 bits. So for example `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` creates a valid key pair `id_rsa, id_rsa.pub`.

Hm, reading what I just posted, I think maybe I just didn't write `yes` when prompted (see the error message above)... Maybe that used to be the default and now it says `[fingerprint]` as the default... Anyway maybe someone equally confused will be helped by this :D