# ssh-agent not found when doing "eval $(ssh-agent -s)"

Tags: git, ssh

So I want to push my local repo to my remote repo on github.com but the problem is that I everytime I generate a new SSH Key and add a it to my account. it doesn't work, then I tried searching through documentations and found out that I have to start my ssh-agent first. but when I do

`eval $(ssh-agent -s)`
it returns
`bash: ssh-agent: command not found`

OS: Windows 10 (I'm using Git bash)

Comment: You need to install `ssh-agent` before you can use it.

Comment: Also, on Windows, think about using Pageant  (the PuTTY SSH agent) instead, and telling git to use `plink` (PuTTY's interface amenable to programmable use). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110079/git-bash-and-pageant-are-not-using-keys describing how to accomplish both these things -- that way other Windows tools (not just PuTTY but also WinSCP f/e) will also be able to use your key.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah thank you! but that's a little strange considering the fact that it worked before.

Comment: Did you mention in the question that it had worked in the past? Anyhow -- check if you have a `ssh-agent.exe` somewhere on your system, and if it does exist, make sure it's in your PATH. (That said, I use Pageant myself on the rare occasions when I have no choice but to work on Windows, and do continue to suggest that you do likewise; you get a tray icon and otherwise generally better platform integration).

Answer (score 1):

The ssh-agent is only needed if you have generated a private key with a passphrase.

Try `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to see where `ssh.exe` would search your key.

And make sure `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin` is in your `%PATH%`, since both `ssh.exe` and `ssh-keygen.exe` are there.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add quotes.

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Comment: This does not work