# Node.JS exec git command error: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, ssh

Question: How can I run `git push` from `node.js` with `passphrase`.

I'm trying to build a small module where I need to run `git push` from `node.js` to a remote `repo`, but I'm getting an error when I with from `node.js exec` but not from the terminal.

My code.

`./command.ts`

```
import * as util from 'util';

const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

export default function command(command: string): Promise<string> {
  return exec(command, {cwd: process.cwd()}).then((resp) => {
    const data = resp.stdout.toString().replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  });
}
```

`./index.ts`

```
import command from './command';

async function init() {
 try {
  await command('git add .');
  await command('git commit -m "my commit" ');
  conat result = await command('git push');
 } catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
 }
}

init();
```

and when I run `ts-node ./index.ts` I get the following error.

```
Error: Command failed: git push                                                                                                         
git@hostname.org: Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                       
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                           

Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                     
and the repository exists.
```

But when I run `git push` from the terminal I get prompt with the passphrase and it works.

Any idea on how to solve this issue, is there a way to run `git push` with passphrase using `node.js`?

bear in mind that I will love to fix this without any external libs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In case you are okay with using username and password you could easily do `git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git --all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [described here](http://bisaga.com/blog/programming/setting-up-the-environment-for-nodejs-and-typescript/), check if the same program works when:

- ssh-agent is launched
- your [key is ssh-add'ed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/6309)

Not only the prompt should no longer query for your passphrase (now cached by the agent), but your script might benefit from that cache as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works however if the there is no ssh key the user will be prompt with the username and pass

Comment: @diegoddox Well yes... but in your case, there is an ssh key, right?

Comment: I do but the people that I will be handed over the module may not have, the best will be if the `exec` could prompt the `passphrase/user:pass` in case of need.

Comment: @diegoddox Then an https URL might be better: they can cache their own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `env: process.env` to your `exec()` options if your key is loaded into an ssh-agent process. There are some environment variables ssh-agent exports that other processes use to find ssh-agent to access its keys.