# Windows 10 - How to get ssh to communicate with ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh

With Windows 10 Pro (1909) ssh does not seem to communicate with ssh-agent. In cmd or powershell, when checking `ssh-add -l` the keys are listed. When connecting to the remote host via `ssh`, the passphrase is still requested.

The only suggestion I've found online is to ensure ssh-agent is running. It is running, since ssh-add connects to it.

Comment: This is off topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri It's similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17848593#17848593 . Not a duplicate though because I'm asking specifically for Windows 10 and I have ensured that ssh-agent is working.

Comment: Same problem, and SO seems 99% full of answers that pre-date the existence of Windows SSH. Did you ever get this to work? Microsoft's own official docs definitely do NOT work