# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent, ssh on ubuntu

Tags: github

i have spent lot of time to solve but still
my ssh is running

```
wahyono17@komputer2:~$ ps -e |grep [s]sh-agent
 2311 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
 2343 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent
```

but when i add ssh there is error

```
wahyono17@komputer2:~$ sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

when i try next step there is error

```
wahyono17@komputer2:~$ sudo ssh-add -L
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent
```

i try to direct to check to github connection but there is error

```
wahyono17@komputer2:~$ sudo ssh -T git@github.com
Permission denied (publickey)
```

public already in github, i have save public key into github, but still there is error

thank for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you started ssh-agent?

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

Comment: that because of permission file in id_rsa and id_rsa.pub, if try in centos there is no problem

Answer (score 4):

eval `ssh-agent` Make sure you use the backquote ( ` ), located under the tilde ( ~ ), rather than the single quote ( ‘ ).

Comment: Unbelievable that this is the answer. Unbelievable.