# Not able to connect to a running SSH Agent

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to use SSH Agent for a git authentication. My environment is Ubuntu Linux in Docker on ECS. I'm starting the SSH Agent when the container starts with a command:

```
runuser -l user -c 'ssh-agent -d'
```

That starts agent using user `user` with debug. Right after that, I wrote `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` into `/home/user/.profile` to make possible to connect to agent for the `user`.

When I log in as a `user`, I can see that my env variables are ok:

```
[user]$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK && echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
/tmp/ssh-z5omIr4XkN49/agent.65
65
```

And the agent is running:

```
[user]$ ps -efal | grep ssh-agent
4 S root        62    59  0  80   0 - 37521 -      14:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64 /usr/sbin/runuser -l user -c ssh-agent -d
4 S user        65    62  0  80   0 - 37672 -      14:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/qemu-x86_64 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -d
```

And socket permissions are fine:

```
[user]$ ls -lh /tmp/ssh-FMgHCgorQ36E/agent.65
srw------- 1 user root 0 Mar 12 14:32 /tmp/ssh-FMgHCgorQ36E/agent.65
```

But when I'm trying to use the `ssd-add` command, I'm getting a connection error:

```
[user]$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

I checked out this answer ([Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)) but it does not work for me because I have to start SSH Agent in my script, without forcing the `user` to do that.

--

**UPDATE**

I guess that `ssh-add` does not read env variables for some reason.

The `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is set:

```
[user]$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-FN4YayNM6fJ1/agent.65
```

But:

```
[user]$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

But **this** works:

```
[user]$ SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-FN4YayNM6fJ1/agent.65 ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:xvtWid6fm7C9LgyhosVOULo9HZQchve4rUVUgUO2zqE (stdin) (RSA)
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I was confused about the `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` result.

I **missed the `export` keyword** when updating the `.profile` file by my script.

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Y3YbbJ4ZTGyp/agent.59
SSH_AGENT_PID=59
```

should be:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-Y3YbbJ4ZTGyp/agent.59
export SSH_AGENT_PID=59
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SSH_AGENT_PID (59) is not right, you should use 65.

Comment: Yes, you're right, great catch! But unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference, still getting the same error.