# add ssh on arch linux

Tags: php, archlinux, manjaro

I am trying to access with ssh in to bit bucket .
I am able to access using my key - id_rsa .
But I am trying to make a different key for bit bucket , but I am having ptoblem to add this new key .

I am following this tutorial -
https://saranonearth.medium.com/setting-up-ssh-access-to-your-bitbucket-account-2ccdae7b266f

but when I run the command -

```
sudo ssh-add ~/.ssh/rsa_bitbucket
```

it says -

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

I cant add this new key , I am using ( Manjaro / Arch linux )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: This question looks as if could be answered (or a ready answer even found) on [su].

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `cat ~/.ssh/rsa_bitbucket.pub` and copy the output from your terminal and then paste it in your bitbucket account. You can find this setting under `Personal Settings > Security > SSH Keys`.

For arch linux you have to install Keychain:

`pacman -S keychain`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Keychain