# Git Extensions custom SSH-Port

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssh, git-extensions

I want to use Git Extensions in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. For security reasons, I'm using a custom ssh-port (lets say 1234) instead of 22 which is the default one.
I did some investigation in the internet and found out that there are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Setting the port in .ssh/config for my host
2. Using the ssh-scheme like this: ssh://git@domain.com:{port}/{project path}

The first one is not possible because I'm using Windows as Client-OS. 
So i tried using ssh like this:

```
ssh://myusername@mydomain.com:1234/root/testapplication.git
```

But it's not working. Git is ignoring my custom port 1234 and always connect on 22. I can use the URL above with ssh-server running on port 22 at mydomain.com.

Whats wrong here? I can't belive that it seems not possible to use a custom ssh port on a Windows-Client...

Comment: Why is the first one not possible? Which ssh client are you using?

Comment: I'm using putty with Pageagent. But it seems that git is ignoring the settings from putty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitExtensions + Putty via SSH on custom port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300647/gitextensions-putty-via-ssh-on-custom-port)

Comment: Kudos to @KurzedMetal, I've deleted my answer in favor of the dupe.